# Summernote is not working even when I included all of the libraries that they instructed us to do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, summernote

I am trying to use summernote for a web app that I have been working on. I believe that I have included all the libraries and followed all of the instructions that they include at [the summernote installation page,](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#installation) but the page returns with nothing. Here is my code (When I run on my own page, it shows no errors in chrome developer tools):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.editor').summernote({
    height: 300, // set editor height
    minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
    maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
    focus: true // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
  });

});
```

```html
<!-- Insrt Libraries and Stylesheets -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Initialize The Div in which the editor goes in -->
<div class=".editor">




</div>
```

**Thanks in advance, 
Tommy John
**

Comment: Use `$(document).ready(` instead of first `$(`

Comment: Thanks for the support, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Also, you should use `https` for bootstrap and summernote sources.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to inform that all of this code is in a modal

Comment: It does not matter where you use it. Browser blocks mixed content on `https` pages, so boostrap and summernote js and css files cannot be loaded - and, therefore, used. Change all `http` source links to `https`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div is not getting initialized in which the editor goes in. 
please change 
`<div class=".editor"></div>`
to 
`<div class="editor"></div>`